# Is there a way to ignore data type mismatch while parsing JSON string into a Protobuff message?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Protobuf library version: 3.21.12
This is my proto file:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message MyBidRequest {
  optional string req_id = 1;
  optional int32 tmax = 2;
}
```

```
    // Read JSON string from a file or any source
    std::string json_string = R"( 
    {
      "req_id": 1,
      "tmax": 777
    }
  )";

    // Create an instance of the protobuf message
    MyBidRequest my_bid_request;

    // Parse the JSON string into the protobuf message

    google::protobuf::util::Status myStatus = google::protobuf::util::JsonStringToMessage(json_string, &my_bid_request);

    std::cout << "Jsonstring to Message Status string:" << myStatus.ToString() << std::endl
  
    // Access the fields of the protobuf message
    std::cout << "1:Field req_id: " << my_bid_request.req_id() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1:Field tmax: " << my_bid_request.tmax() << std::endl;
```

Output on running the above code:

```
Jsonstring to Message Status string:INVALID_ARGUMENT:(req_id): invalid value 1 for type TYPE_STRING
1:Field req_id: 
1:Field tmax: 0
```

Even when a single field's data type is mismatched, complete json parsing failure happens.What I am trying to achieve is that the tmax field should get consumed even when id is not a string, is there a way I can achieve this?

The JSON can have ~100 fields. Loss of the whole JSON is not what we want, since it will lead to a lost opportunity. The single mismatched field, which can be an insignificant one, can be discarded, and we could use the rest 99. The discarded fields can be given some default value and used depending on use case of each field. In case the field is a significant one, it will be in the hands of application to discard the whole JSON. We want the control to discard the whole JSON on the application side, instead of the library

Comment: You could just use a regular JSON parser instead of using a tool that is specifically designed to test the validity of the consumed message.

Comment: Hi @john , the reason we want to use protobuf library for json parsing is that the JSON schema is expected to change time to time, and we want to minimize JSON parsing efforts as much as possible. Hence we are looking for some parser that will parse the schema given to it beforehand, and we need not write any code for parsing the JSON object. Any changes made in schema definition should take care of parsing is what we are looking for, along with low latency. Is there any such parser available? As per my knowledge no other schema based fast parser with low latency is available

Comment: @AtharvaJoshi: Why is it useful to you to have an invalid JSON message partially parsed? For what would you use the partially parsed message (with some fields, i.e. those with errors, removed)? How can a partially parsed message, with random fields removed be useful?

Comment: @pts Thanks for your response. The JSON can have ~100 fields. Loss of the whole JSON is not what we want, since it will lead to a lost opportunity. The single mismatched field, which can be an insignificant one, can be discarded, and we could use the rest 99. The discarded fields can be given some default value and used depending on use case of each field. In case the field is a significant one, it will be in the hands of application to discard the whole JSON. We want the control to discard the whole JSON on the application side, instead of the library.

Comment: You may want to add your last comment to your question. Anyways, protobuf doesn't supoort your use case (in which the application controls what should happen to fields of an invalid type).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the requested behavior is impossible with `google::protobuf::util::JsonStringToMessage`. Typically protobuf is designed to completely fail on invalid messages, code for partial or lenient parsing is not implemented.

As a workaround, you can have multiple `message` definitions in your .proto file (e.g. one with `int`, another one with `string`), and call `google::protobuf::util::JsonStringToMessage` with the same JSON input on each.

Typically if you change the type of a field, and you still want to be able to parse old messages, then you should introduce a new field in the .proto file, like this:

```
message MyBidRequest {
  oneof req_id_oneof {
    // In new messages (since version X), use .req_id_x instead.
    optional int64 req_id = 1;
    optional string req_id_x = 11;
  }
  optional int32 tmax = 2;
}
```